# Wireless connection working only when a computer is connected through LAN to the router

Tags: router, wireless-networking

I have a TP-Link WR740N router connected to the internet via PPPoE.
I have a PC connected to it via LAN (to the first LAN port - if it makes any difference) and few mobile devices via WIFI.

The problem is that whenever the computer disconnects from the network (the computer is shutdown), the WIFI while active, will also stop not connect to the Internet.

In the router's system log I see the status: "PPPOE hardline is disconnected".

As soon as the computer will be turned on (while connected to the LAN) the WIFI starts connecting to the Internet again.
The router's system log register the status: "PPPOE connected".

I tried to set the router's "Connection Mode" to remain active all the time, but nothing changed.

What can I do? (sorry for my bad english)

**Later edit** I've discovered that if I connect the computer to any other  LAN port than the first one, the computer will not connect to the internet (while I can connect to the router). In the router's system log I see the status: "PPPOE hardline is disconnected".

Comment: You don't provide enough detail. For instance, what is the router make and model? Please edit your question with as much detail as possible.

Comment: "Wifi stops working" and "can't connect to the internet" are two very different things. Please check which one it is.  To check wifi: ping the router from any wifi-capable device. Another thing to check is whether the cable that goes to your modem is actually connected to the WAN port and not to a LAN port by mistake.

Comment: I edited the question. The wifi is active but doesn't connect to the internet. The cables are connected to the right ports (the modem cable is connected to the WAN and the cable from the computer to the first LAN port).

Comment: Did you previously configure the PPOE connection directly on the computer (without the router)?

Comment: @Bram No, But I've tried cloning the MAC address. Same behavior...

Comment: What's your WAN Connection Type and WAN Connection Mode? Try to look in kind of diagnostics or status page for a state of your WAN link when you disable LAN#1.

Comment: @g2mk As I mentioned in the question, it's a PPPoE connection, the Mode is Connect on Demand wit 0 minutes (that is active at all times)

Comment: @sica07 Sorry. Are you trying Connect Automatically instead of Connect on Demand wit 0 minutes?

Comment: @g2mk I've tried Connect Automatically but nothing changed.

Comment: @sica07 Have you the newest firmware? It seems that V4 fix "Fixed a bug that PPPOE can't dial up successfully in some special situations" and better is to reboot after settings change.

Comment: "hard line" means "cable", and all ports on the router should work equally well. I suggest: (1) Check your cable to the router and maybe try another one. (2) Check for updates to your network adapter driver and the router's firmware, (3) Reset the router to factory defaults. (4) Try another router.